# use std::stable_partition and ::iterator with a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to organize a vector that could contain this:

```
[0]:  "people:"
[1]:  "James"
[2]:  "Jhones"
[3]:  "unknown person"
[4]:  "Mary"
[5]:  "Bob"
[6]:  "unknown person"
[7]:  "hobbies:"
[8]:  "Baseball"
[9]:  "unknown hobbies"
[10]: "Ping-pong"
[11]: "FootBall"
[12]: "unknown hobbies"
...
```

In order to organize the information, I would like each string beginning with the term "unknown" to be "go up" just below the last value ending with ":"

Which would give me:

```
[0]:  "people:"
[1]:  "unknown person"
[2]:  "unknown person"
[3]:  "James"
[4]:  "Jhones"
[5]:  "Mary"
[6]:  "Bob"
[7]:  "hobbies:"
[8]:  "unknown hobbies"
[9]:  "unknown hobbies"
[10]: "Baseball"
[11]: "Ping-pong"
[12]: "FootBall"
...
```

To do this, I have decided to use std::stable_partition. This is my function:

```
std::vector<std::string> Organize(std::vector<std::string> vec) {
    using namespace std;
    auto it = find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](auto a) {return a.back() == ':'; });
    stable_partition(it.base(), vec.end(), [](string s) {return s_startswith(s, "unknown"); });
    for (string str : vec)
        cout << " --> " << str << endl;
    return vec;
}
```

voici ma fonction s_startswith :

```
bool s_startswith(std::string const &str, std::string const &fnd) {
    return (str.rfind(fnd, 0) == 0);
}
```

I thought it might have worked, but I have this error message displayed:

[image: I think I understand what causes the error, but I don't know how to correct it...]

Don't worry if this "organization" doesn't make sense. It is perfect, but I have made it much simpler in order to see the essential.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Use a debugger. It must help you.

Comment: The visual studio debugger tells me that the problem occurs from the variable "it", then it shows me the error message. I know where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is in the lamda. The string `a` is empty. Access `a.back()` is invalid.

```
auto it = find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), [](auto a) {return a.back() == ':'; });
```

Make sure all vector elements are not empty.

Comment: Yes, it does work, thank's. There must have been empty bins in the vector. However, this change is only for the last elements, not the first ones. If I use my example (1st message), only the elements under the "hobbies" label are affected by the modification. Would there be a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Maybe you need `return !a.empty() && a.back() == ':';`

Comment: Well, here's the result: https://i.imgur.com/MHJ5pLd.png .So, as you can see, it works well, but only for the last values after the last label (so term ending with ":"). My question is whether we know how to do this for all the labels and their values.
I hope it's clearer :)

Comment: You should do it in a loop. something like this: `end = it.base(); it = find_if(it, vec.rend(), ...); stable_partition(it.base(), end, ...);`  I do not want to code it for you.

Comment: I didn't ask you to code it for me, don't worry about it :)
Thank you for everything! My problem is now solved.